# Improve copy-pasting of furigana

Tags: html, cjk, ruby-characters

I have the following markup:

```
<ruby><rb>ネックスス</rb><rp>［</rp><rt>Ｎｅｘｕｓ</rt><rp>］</rp></ruby>
```

It [renders](http://jsfiddle.net/wLSQc/1/) very nicely in Chrome and IE (gasp!) and makes correct use of the fallback rendering in Firefox (not that it has any choice in the matter, just ignoring the unknown tags is how the fallback works).

However, I have noticed that IE and Chrome do not factor in the `<rp>` elements when copying the text to the clipboard. Attempting to copy it should result in `ネックスス［Ｎｅｘｕｓ］`, but instead yields the parentheses-less `ネックススＮｅｘｕｓ`, somewhat defeating the purpose of furigana (imagine how that would look in a more "usual" situation of having kanji as the base and kana as the furi...)

Is there any way I can fix this, or is this a browser issue?

Comment: As an aside, if my katakana is wrong, please feel free to correct me on that - I'm trying to learn but sometimes I get mixed up!

Comment: Firefox 28.0 no problem, and feels nice.

Comment: Your katakana is good. Nekkususu.

Comment: Hmm... another aside, I just tried to use the `<rbc>`/`<rtc>` elements to group the katakana with their associated romaji, but doing so causes both Chrome and IE to stop rendering it as furigana... worse, they fail to add in the parentheses... Oh well.

Comment: Any fiddle about that?

Comment: @Jamie [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/wLSQc/2/)

Comment: Firefox snapshot : [here](http://s14.postimg.org/roa7jbdwg/Firefox.jpg)

Comment: @Jamie That's fine, because Firefox doesn't recognise `<ruby>` at all and just uses the fallback method of just displaying the plain text. IE and Chrome don't handle rbc/rtc correctly.

Comment: Then you'd better find another way to do so. The simplest way could be using `img` or something other than `ruby`. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ruby.asp) out

Comment: @Jamie Fair enough. Getting back to the original question, though, any idea how I might make IE and Chrome recognise the `<rp>` elements for copying?

Comment: Nope. I haven't got any ideas. Seems that a bounty should be thrown.